# R: optimization based on historical data

Tags: r, optimization

I have a matrix of monthly returns and a vector of forecasts.  I want to minimize my risk for a given level of return (based on the forecast).  The forecasts are just the anticipated % change in value of the asset.  The risk is based on the 5th percentile of the vector that is the result of passing a given portfolio through the monthly returns:

```
library(nloptr)
library(ggplot2)

#load csv files
balances<-as.matrix(t(c(-3300000, 2000000, -7700000, 5500000, -4000000, 1000000)))
forecast<-as.matrix(t(c(-0.000768006, 0.000635124, 0.001526249, -0.008919934, 0.000152549, 0.001271481)))
mReturns<-read.csv(file="C:/Users/Desktop/mReturns.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", row.names=1)

mReturns<-round(mReturns, digits=8)
forecast<-round(forecast, digits=8)

colnames(balances)<-letters[1:ncol(balances)]
colnames(forecast)<-letters[1:ncol(forecast)]
colnames(mReturns)<-letters[1:ncol(forecast)]

#Minimize Variance:
fn <- function(H) {
    X<-balances * (1 - H)
    Y<-t(t(mReturns) * as.vector(X))
    return(quantile(rowSums(Y), .05, na.rm=TRUE))
}

fn2 <- function(H) {
    return(-fn(H))
}

#For a given forecast:
target<-0
eqn <- function(H) {
    X <- balances * (H)
    return(sum(X * forecast) - target)
}

loops<-6
n<-length(balances)

# Initialize a matrix to contain allocation and statistics
eff<-matrix(nrow=2+loops, ncol=n+3)
colnames(eff) <- c(colnames(balances), "Target", "Variance", "Forecast")

#Find the forecast for the 100% strategy
pars <-rep(1, n)
eff[1,1:n]<-pars
eff[1,n+2]<-fn(pars)
eff[1,n+3]<-eqn(pars)

#Find the strategy that maximizes forecast
pars2<-rep(0,n)
pars2[which(balances*forecast>=0)]<-1
eff[2,1:n]<-pars2
eff[2,n+2]<-fn(pars2)
eff[2,n+3]<-eqn(pars2)

#Constrain the values in H
lH<-rep(0, ncol(balances))
uH<-rep(1,ncol(balances))

pars2<-rep(1, n)  #initial guess is all 1's

increment = (eff[2,n+3]-eff[1,n+3])/(loops+1)
for (i in 1:loops) {
    target<-c(eff[2,n+3]-(i)*increment)  #target forecast
    sol <- auglag(pars, fn=fn2, gr=NULL, heq=eqn, lower=lH, upper=uH, nl.info = FALSE, control = list(xtol_rel = 1e-8, maxeval = 20000))
    targetHolder<-target
    target<-0
    eff[i+2,]<-c(sol$par, targetHolder, fn(sol$par), eqn(sol$par))
}

#Random Portfolios
set.seed(10)
randoms<-matrix(runif(10000*ncol(balances)), ncol=ncol(balances))
dots<-cbind(apply(randoms, 1, fn), apply(randoms, 1, eqn))

#graph
x11()
eff<-as.data.frame(eff)
dots<-as.data.frame(dots)

ggplot() +
    geom_point(data=dots, aes(V1, V2),size=3, color=rgb(115,150,0,max=255)) +
    geom_line(data=eff, aes(Variance, Forecast), size=1, color=rgb(187,8,38, max=255)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
    ggtitle("Frontier") +
    labs(x="Variance", y="Forecast") +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_x_continuous(labels = comma) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
    geom_point(data=eff, aes(Variance, Forecast),size=3, color=rgb(187,8,38,max=255))
```

monthly returns (this is the best set I can get for illustrating the problem):

```
                    AAA           BBB           CCC           DDD           EEE           FFF
10/1/2006 -0.0273758311 -0.0173219254 -0.0092231793 -0.0138312574 -0.0124329157 -0.0124668848
11/1/2006  0.0386007238  0.0195502377  0.0097401588  0.0115189105 -0.0125419543  0.0065488401
12/1/2006  0.0180668473  0.0380363598  0.0137722146 -0.0103839765 -0.0110926718  0.0454652348
1/1/2007   0.0006337939 -0.0111542926 -0.0301578502  0.0142295446 -0.0180118359 -0.0101971958
2/1/2007  -0.0193818090  0.0038791343 -0.0147327469  0.0171395937 -0.0106915572 -0.0135595788
3/1/2007   0.0136933213 -0.0042708969  0.0272062488 -0.0086841626  0.0051172709  0.0125940716
4/1/2007   0.0304574997  0.0047998366 -0.0017821783  0.0288433537  0.0160311962  0.0127407857
5/1/2007   0.0233737324  0.0157028153 -0.0170184226  0.0122388783  0.0387973703  0.0187209825
6/1/2007   0.0067673716 -0.0081553009 -0.0182637526  0.0680350676  0.0472285071 -0.0113937077
7/1/2007   0.0195654783  0.0132667474 -0.0086871710 -0.0124935191 -0.0042241618  0.0068406573
8/1/2007   0.0076524606  0.0118484592  0.0353900671  0.0249734320  0.0087112958  0.0093050735
9/1/2007  -0.0435798575 -0.0075768758  0.0275545857 -0.0407258270  0.0004736651 -0.0027072510
10/1/2007  0.0924749572  0.0130880968  0.0002592090  0.0845218362  0.0644348088  0.0440939105
11/1/2007  0.0201274740  0.0179104478  0.0093311906  0.0350746684  0.0427970555  0.0136322114
12/1/2007 -0.0305820454 -0.0114417576  0.0308341887 -0.0249386286 -0.0477620911  0.0144194107
1/1/2008  -0.0093848937 -0.0339930944 -0.0036721437  0.0069662916  0.0061454765 -0.0028018861
2/1/2008   0.0321881064 -0.0107229158  0.0484552051  0.0198235360 -0.0027127500  0.0143914474
3/1/2008   0.0294150171  0.0122131189  0.0265085560  0.0323534622  0.0075926301  0.0254695311
4/1/2008  -0.0254592330 -0.0066361671  0.0185567006 -0.0307842234 -0.0328013313  0.0286580144
5/1/2008   0.0291005291 -0.0005567083 -0.0247055516  0.0492000484  0.0012745099 -0.0089663123
6/1/2008   0.0239931448  0.0037978529 -0.0103297983  0.0218807620  0.0267767258  0.0051699625
7/1/2008  -0.0010460251  0.0063562528 -0.0057476747  0.0181476849 -0.0281745247  0.0153658223
8/1/2008  -0.0270157068 -0.0099754374 -0.0146689710  0.0243589740 -0.0048676019 -0.0145000950
9/1/2008  -0.0848041326 -0.0878987342 -0.0039763301 -0.0543735223 -0.0370300926 -0.0608455410
10/1/2008 -0.0740827846 -0.0175974242  0.0228906428 -0.1397058821  0.0037639971 -0.0415954026
11/1/2008 -0.1518923038 -0.0915974459  0.0736264752 -0.1118110238 -0.1235463915 -0.0915839817
12/1/2008 -0.0413297394 -0.0741477980  0.0566584579 -0.0762846012 -0.0286790030 -0.0090366179
1/1/2009   0.1018431740 -0.0138403655  0.0268870859  0.0098509388  0.0231128587  0.1137102530
2/1/2009  -0.0962574426 -0.0094018259  0.0092303638 -0.0036590625 -0.0077260893 -0.0877180491
3/1/2009   0.0023529412 -0.0152682256 -0.0784996236 -0.0266487893 -0.0365901429 -0.0112385858
4/1/2009   0.0943661972  0.0104763235 -0.0096417819  0.0496085860  0.0129365079  0.0457810403
5/1/2009   0.0447590448  0.0313104783 -0.0059523944  0.0459061643  0.0631117103  0.0018114575
6/1/2009   0.1088146729  0.1020038871  0.0261932537  0.1138436318  0.0838591685  0.0667520530
7/1/2009  -0.0019750648  0.0021285653 -0.0007242318  0.0099870620 -0.0487995829 -0.0012006498
8/1/2009   0.0338899196  0.0142614395  0.0209125845  0.0361374737  0.0668151452  0.0081318060
9/1/2009  -0.0118435220 -0.0330880153  0.0189410175 -0.0253958301 -0.0240898396 -0.0023146525
10/1/2009  0.0529055690 -0.0126856436  0.0369378363  0.0711407143  0.0187286653  0.0225674916
11/1/2009  0.0344946533  0.0312127860 -0.0053280313  0.0144219837 -0.0008296452  0.0119628738
12/1/2009  0.0281204846  0.0096031119  0.0393401412  0.0235369340  0.0368954311  0.0245940621
1/1/2010  -0.0291891892 -0.0276924929 -0.0683577530 -0.0136428779 -0.0062689978 -0.0501956104
2/1/2010  -0.0073496659 -0.0119497245  0.0268182226 -0.0560575728 -0.0073543270 -0.0274364703
3/1/2010   0.0106573929 -0.0605965660  0.0166050081  0.0279786409  0.0184367195 -0.0266312540
4/1/2010   0.0224220224  0.0200787139 -0.0499893623  0.0188144624  0.0325203247  0.0021386431
5/1/2010   0.0034741070 -0.0011770861 -0.0003196447  0.0144877542 -0.0091364566 -0.0217087350
6/1/2010  -0.1007248729 -0.0407882676  0.0318856314 -0.0586643576 -0.0355315523 -0.0801113284
7/1/2010   0.0146775746  0.0359019862  0.0382420201  0.0316565244 -0.0039637605  0.0243683048
8/1/2010   0.0720891629  0.0337352573  0.0130681681  0.0206279554  0.0290375846  0.0419094755
9/1/2010   0.0082946251 -0.0149149085  0.0240407343  0.0050973650 -0.0191465044 -0.0186178363
10/1/2010  0.0665789185  0.0238757684  0.0146598812  0.0333195239  0.0295184853  0.0766648450
11/1/2010  0.0151172357  0.0133973711  0.0336604101 -0.0078097478  0.0044326247  0.0073961279
12/1/2010 -0.0190456894 -0.0257545523 -0.0437106512 -0.0011144347 -0.0017699119 -0.0542719355
1/1/2011   0.0568005783 -0.0007040901  0.0378451737  0.0262445077  0.0190380763  0.0186467768
2/1/2011  -0.0119222124  0.0339482449 -0.0028272754 -0.0018625333  0.0074702196  0.0332486551
3/1/2011   0.0022747503  0.0077437740 -0.0062301897  0.0003004991  0.0162084538 -0.0037602140
4/1/2011   0.0249654628 -0.0095899674 -0.0261717073  0.0354075923  0.0120431890  0.0333889816
5/1/2011   0.0562241263  0.0369933586  0.0353491621  0.0200583972  0.0191514125  0.0400365245
6/1/2011  -0.0325403336 -0.0223259711  0.0029648152 -0.0117927481 -0.0328489560 -0.0323495644
7/1/2011   0.0146975692 -0.0159177176  0.0014845420  0.0245501284  0.0195096504  0.0138190955
8/1/2011   0.0186629526  0.0138111236  0.0468851189 -0.0064491408  0.0015673977 -0.0190004131
9/1/2011  -0.0226961991 -0.0071796760  0.0036396795 -0.0330925481 -0.0203705594  0.0006315789
10/1/2011 -0.0988621526 -0.0367760677 -0.0016869980 -0.1381365404 -0.0698847952 -0.0611543587
11/1/2011  0.0690333264  0.0234214579 -0.0167155471  0.0770244711  0.0293022346  0.0236049899
12/1/2011 -0.0082292574 -0.0162392626  0.0086228941 -0.0306649633  0.0064108885 -0.0176603663
1/1/2012  -0.0034166341 -0.0093690249  0.0102717068 -0.0357295909 -0.0072456670 -0.0371443429
2/1/2012   0.0485845822  0.0187222544  0.0093176468  0.0763997010  0.0227318248  0.0154309081
3/1/2012   0.0097150864  0.0077680940 -0.0606509309  0.0117255850  0.0132927441  0.0113973102
4/1/2012  -0.0428346748  0.0031960895 -0.0211174021 -0.0616378357 -0.0132171821  0.0024040267
5/1/2012  -0.0011598685  0.0133058471  0.0347109283 -0.0427081690  0.0134970570 -0.0079442404
6/1/2012  -0.0612541126 -0.0528943962  0.0265316552 -0.0646046778 -0.0534101827 -0.0606632923
7/1/2012   0.0553551180  0.0223914600 -0.0221831931  0.0152781926  0.0240015740  0.0187389416
8/1/2012   0.0217815980 -0.0108868657  0.0172106230 -0.0170718584  0.0109387431 -0.0348938186
9/1/2012  -0.0132874486  0.0212409887  0.0006377956  0.0066476282  0.0195680830  0.0289570552
10/1/2012  0.0037783375  0.0166393546  0.0051289010  0.0019735538  0.0040720757  0.0245647508
11/1/2012  0.0038606312  0.0000000000 -0.0265851526 -0.0022644484 -0.0142498744  0.0042675357
12/1/2012  0.0025959042 -0.0072535648 -0.0286130154 -0.0489700375  0.0021118266  0.0033222591
1/1/2013  -0.0031645570  0.0147380254 -0.0486735937  0.0411386231  0.0010066431  0.0167873094
2/1/2013   0.0011544012 -0.0342174903 -0.0654305847  0.0319919529 -0.0031108877  0.0330202969
3/1/2013  -0.0196021908 -0.0417383547 -0.0087616625  0.0041925528 -0.0295091542 -0.0453079179
4/1/2013   0.0215622856  0.0127011571  0.0038614299 -0.0203384796  0.0098347756 -0.0132852096
5/1/2013  -0.0138156001  0.0214065270 -0.0427148166  0.0097436671  0.0084300305  0.0257607596
6/1/2013  -0.0688782956 -0.0229508197 -0.0304629093 -0.0652935412 -0.0281445781 -0.0137329287
7/1/2013  -0.0347926027  0.0012501645  0.0079269110 -0.0394347242 -0.0116223686  0.0050003846
8/1/2013  -0.0338817926 -0.0063744496  0.0012055870 -0.0326360551  0.0145950131  0.0109461115
9/1/2013  -0.0026890756  0.0253968254  0.0139553083 -0.0340809061 -0.0181266017  0.0011357613
10/1/2013  0.0558364229  0.0445691434  0.0017347621  0.0762463339  0.0208292961  0.0229919831
11/1/2013  0.0042562247 -0.0166100648 -0.0067903218 -0.0165498253 -0.0094049904 -0.0028833358
12/1/2013 -0.0349650350  0.0277533593 -0.0368020343 -0.0351883563 -0.0182777460  0.0077111292
1/1/2014  -0.0243741765  0.0120967742 -0.0266983220 -0.0110494902 -0.0028184893  0.0126554337
2/1/2014  -0.0146297547 -0.0076663045  0.0314581713 -0.0210129322 -0.0434938896 -0.0201264259
3/1/2014   0.0191868433  0.0186142709  0.0023576343  0.0292198115  0.0057845269  0.0234317070
4/1/2014   0.0361945316 -0.0068677217 -0.0178485935  0.0364295499  0.0036284465 -0.0006520794
5/1/2014   0.0029198659  0.0158147925  0.0128994503  0.0132598662  0.0062066454  0.0055825419
6/1/2014   0.0038818201 -0.0081690641  0.0055025913 -0.0041043938  0.0101419878 -0.0169430425
7/1/2014   0.0200859291  0.0235750522  0.0023639137  0.0179844668  0.0201279157  0.0032269894
8/1/2014  -0.0194798357 -0.0191836735 -0.0105253101 -0.0247154181 -0.0260168559 -0.0184223993
9/1/2014   0.0021477663 -0.0126627430 -0.0166746378  0.0052540178  0.0041394531 -0.0222685633
10/1/2014 -0.0636519503 -0.0254094412 -0.0416934585 -0.0947966609 -0.0261578426 -0.0384673979
11/1/2014  0.0068665599 -0.0118003213 -0.0305377641  0.0013318247 -0.0091425528 -0.0077636061
12/1/2014 -0.0348942942 -0.0165676774 -0.0513513556 -0.0323739586 -0.0055609505 -0.0043912176
1/1/2015  -0.0362737016 -0.0091544819 -0.0111909311 -0.0364614693 -0.0242873130 -0.0293504411
2/1/2015  -0.0514481242 -0.0337482356  0.0191506171 -0.0094300950 -0.0880458693 -0.0671678784
3/1/2015   0.0059263077  0.0250996016 -0.0178885567 -0.0557158943  0.0173391939 -0.0084137809
4/1/2015  -0.0266393443 -0.0398367664 -0.0010855227 -0.1022781142 -0.0083987014 -0.0386745266
5/1/2015   0.0330263158  0.0219253862 -0.0032458554  0.0498921894  0.0379965466  0.0405091517
6/1/2015  -0.0312062158  0.0034988117 -0.0370281860 -0.0485734132 -0.0289889795 -0.0242878828
7/1/2015   0.0051275309  0.0273666206  0.0129901792  0.0060967874 -0.0054011118  0.0115310698
8/1/2015  -0.0440810988  0.0003201639 -0.0058116534 -0.0795580758 -0.0382705683 -0.0062426491
9/1/2015  -0.0395457033 -0.0203559083  0.0378654941 -0.0749722897 -0.0126706388  0.0301347414
10/1/2015  0.0015671748 -0.0113042342 -0.0046693964 -0.0775158974 -0.0006783238 -0.0106053911
11/1/2015  0.0153627312  0.0196285771 -0.0057204213  0.0398620240  0.0143730891 -0.0168825368
12/1/2015  0.0259176240 -0.0224267565 -0.0183120461  0.0007267065 -0.0208114991 -0.0338906051
1/1/2016  -0.0027311211 -0.0222782124  0.0192451285 -0.0272167213 -0.0358715265  0.0209724443
2/1/2016  -0.0258797754 -0.0212260952 -0.0036366319 -0.0007064285 -0.0066676232  0.0029476787
3/1/2016   0.0085746416 -0.0333264048  0.0612226330  0.0074985366  0.0401193145 -0.0018368846
4/1/2016   0.0699651568  0.0197104358  0.0207718249  0.1070122134  0.0306663595  0.0481229297
5/1/2016  -0.0096391820  0.0270612216  0.0487323576  0.0343442572  0.0362376556  0.0052673163
6/1/2016  -0.0455083520 -0.0134136326 -0.0277524101 -0.0460086088 -0.0399143600 -0.0229674264
7/1/2016   0.0332093151 -0.0797031077  0.0684744419  0.1128105301  0.0128562573 -0.0046478370
8/1/2016   0.0050680181 -0.0066329992  0.0012697102 -0.0089113465 -0.0161536118  0.0024245690
9/1/2016   0.0019904459  0.0067531679 -0.0081372403  0.0025174229  0.0016026871  0.003045776
```

As you can see, the red line is not the most efficient set of solutions:
[image]

Comment: There is no data here, only equations. So a firm answer is not possible. But it would help to know WHY you expect your 100 data points to produce a smother line than it has?

Comment: @bethanyP I just added the data if you would like to play with it.  I would expect it to be smooth because, theoretically, I could just make small changes to the weights in H to get from one point to the next.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. What libraries are you using? What is 'forecast'? Put your data in a data frame so people can help you. I recommend that you read ["How to make a great R reproducible example?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @BrianO'Donnell I edited the post, hopefully it is clearer now.  I could use some help on this one.

Comment: Huge improvement!  Only one issue.  If the package 'scales' is not loaded two changes are needed:                                    "scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::comma) + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +"

Comment: It looks like you are attempting to calculate a Pareto Frontier. I'm not familiar with using the package, but I think that `library(GPareto)` might have what you need.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with **quantile spline regression** (package `fields`). Here I did the model to fit 10% of the points (just to run it faster for the example).

```
library(fields)
dots <- dots[base::sample(NROW(dots), 1000), ]
fit90 = qsreg(x=dots$V1, y=dots$V2, alpha=0.95, lam=1E7)
plot(x=dots$V1, y=dots$V2, main=("alpha=95%"))
points(x=dots$V1, y=fitted(fit90), col="red")
```

Then you can tweek the parameters to choose the threshold that suits you (90%, 95%, 99% of the limit of your points) and then play with the lambda argument to get the smoothing you want (it goes fro 0 to infinite..)

[image]

Comment: The thing I don't like about this method is that the red line is only as good as the random sample.  For portfolios with a lot of assets, I often find solutions that are ahead of the field of dots by using an optimizer.

Comment: hi thanks for your feedback, i don't have skills in risk assessment or optimization unfortunately so I can't help your specific domain. But I can suggest statistical ideas to go "further" than 100% quantile, such as increasing the noise to the points that are close to the limit (bootstrap on residuals for instance) or adding weight to some extreme points, etc.

Comment: @user3390169 just one more comment, I think at this point the question is not anymore about a coding problem but more about statistical/optimization science. You could migrate it to the CrossValidated site.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that will help with the visualization is to show opacity.  By adding an alpha to your aesthetics you will see the data in depth better.

For example:

```
ggplot() +
    geom_point(data=dots, aes(V1, V2),size=3, color=rgb(115,150,0,max=255), alpha=0.05) +
    geom_line(data=eff, aes(Variance, Forecast), size=1, color=rgb(187,8,38, max=255)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
    ggtitle("Frontier") +
    labs(x="Variance", y="Forecast") +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_x_continuous(labels = comma) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
    geom_point(data=eff, aes(Variance, Forecast),size=3, color=rgb(187,8,38,max=255))
```

This provides:
[image]

Now your optimization looks a lot better.

Comment: Thank you, that looks cool but I am really looking for an improvement in the efficiency of the solutions on the red line.  All of those points should be on the "northeast" edge of the green points.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a high enough score to comment, but it looks like you need a mean-variance optimisation function. (That said, there are difficulties in this approach: see [a paper that I wrote](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwifnqylipvPAhWkJsAKHZc4B4IQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.towerswatson.com%2FDownloadMedia.aspx%3Fmedia%3D%257B2DDB7037-9E76-4402-9C42-F77945EF217A%257D&usg=AFQjCNEtGuDH6qw9huyaqfLNzVQSBzlipg&sig2=FxlECKQQWA4pIc6p39Rrcg&bvm=bv.133178914,d.ZGg&cad=rja) for more details.)

Anyway, you could try the portfolio.optim function from the package tseries. Here's an example of the code:

```
portfolio.optim(x, pm = mean(x), riskless = FALSE, shorts = FALSE,
rf = 0.0, reslow = NULL, reshigh = NULL, covmat = cov(x), ...)
```

To give you some more background, you may find [these slides](http://www.rinfinance.com/RinFinance2009/presentations/yollin_slides.pdf) useful.

I hope that helps you.

---

**EDIT** (I've now had a bit more time to consider the details.)

From what it seems to me, your investments are a bit counterintuitive. After all, some higher risk investments have the lowest expected returns and vice-versa. Here's the detail:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tseries)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)

# Load csv files (with a modified reference in my code)
forecast<-as.matrix(t(c(-0.000768006, 0.000635124, 0.001526249, -0.008919934, 0.000152549, 0.001271481)))
mReturns<-read.csv(file="mReturns.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", row.names=1)

# Consider inputs to mean-variance optimiser
mRet <- matrix(unlist(mReturns), nrow = 120, ncol = 6, byrow = FALSE)
colnames(mRet) <- c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF")
vc <- cov(mRet)
cor <- cor(mRet)
print(round(cor, 2))
```

That code yields this correlation matrix of monthly returns:

```
     AAA   BBB   CCC  DDD  EEE  FFF
AAA 1.00  0.58  0.05 0.77 0.73 0.74
BBB 0.58  1.00 -0.10 0.45 0.57 0.61
CCC 0.05 -0.10  1.00 0.02 0.01 0.05
DDD 0.77  0.45  0.02 1.00 0.64 0.53
EEE 0.73  0.57  0.01 0.64 1.00 0.57
FFF 0.74  0.61  0.05 0.53 0.57 1.00
```

And now for the other inputs to the optimiser:

```
returnStats <- data_frame(name = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF"), 
                          ret = as.numeric(forecast), 
                          vol = sqrt(apply(mRet, 2, var)))
inputs <- returnStats
inputs[, 2:3] <- round(100*inputs[, 2:3], 2)
print(inputs)
```

And this yields the expected (forecast) return and volatility of each investment:

```
   name   ret   vol
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1   AAA -0.08  4.17
2   BBB  0.06  2.74
3   CCC  0.15  2.84
4   DDD -0.89  4.60
5   EEE  0.02  2.94
6   FFF  0.13  3.12
```

So, as I mentioned above, these are strange inputs (as they've been entered above):

- The investment with the second-lowest volatility has the highest expected return (CCC)
- The highest-volatility investment has the lowest expected return (DDD)

All this makes the prima facie answer quite simple: Allocate lots to CCC. Sure, the second-order impact of diversification may mean that you don't allocate everything to CCC, opting also for some FFF, given its risk-return profile and the low correlation between these two investments.

And all this is confirmed by the end points of the efficient frontier. (I've kept the frontier in return space, as it is easier to interpret. BTW, you could also use the package PortfolioAnalytics if you wanted.)

```
# Build efficient frontier
effFrontier = function (averet, rcov, nports = 8, shorts=FALSE, wmax=1)
{
  mxret = max(abs(averet))
  mnret = -mxret
  n.assets = ncol(averet)
  reshigh = rep(wmax,n.assets)
  if( shorts )
  {
    reslow = rep(-wmax,n.assets)
  } else {
    reslow = rep(0,n.assets)
  }
  min.rets = seq(mnret, mxret, len = nports)
  vol = rep(NA, nports)
  ret = rep(NA, nports)
  for (k in 1:nports)
  {
    port.sol = NULL
    try(port.sol <- portfolio.optim(x=averet, pm=min.rets[k], covmat=rcov,
                                    reshigh=reshigh, reslow=reslow,shorts=shorts),silent=T)
    if ( !is.null(port.sol) )
    {
      vol[k] = sqrt(as.vector(port.sol$pw %*% rcov %*% port.sol$pw))
      ret[k] = averet %*% port.sol$pw
    }
  }
  return(list(vol = vol, ret = ret))
}

# Run efficient frontier
eF <- effFrontier(averet=forecast, rcov=vc, shorts = FALSE, nports = 100)
eff <- as_data_frame(eF)
```

All that remains is to plot this frontier:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=eff, aes(vol, ret), size=1, color=rgb(187,8,38, max=255)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  ggtitle("Frontier") +
  labs(x="Volatility", y="Forecast") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = percent) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  geom_point(data=eff, aes(vol, ret), size=3, color=rgb(187,8,38,max=255))
```

And that code produces this chart:

[image: Portfolio optimisation]

The discontinuity at around 2% volatility and the inversion of this frontier speak to the nature of your investment inputs.

Sorry that the extended answer took a while, but I hope this helps you a bit more.